# For successful build how many test cycles are required

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, manual-testing, agile-testing, agile

In one interview they asked me about the agile testing. "How often testing cycle happens in your project after successful build?" I'm new to agile methodology in testing. Please let me know how to answer this question.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question, but with agile after a successful build you should be testing as often as necessary / feasible to get the product to the required level of quality.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way for you to answer would be something like "I'm new to Agile, so I don't really know."

If you have non-Agile experience, you could expand on your answer and talk about the number of test cycles on the projects you tested.

And if you have read enough about Agile to feel confident that your reading applies to this particular context, then you could say something like "I'm new to Agile, but I have read that ...".

If you don't know a technology or methodology, I find it better not to guess.

Answer (score 0):

For The **Agile Model Driven Development** (AMDD) life cycle, it may depend upon number of factors like

1. Number of user stories to be covered
2. Duration of the Sprint
3. Complexity of the PBI's
4. Number of testers working in that sprint and their efficiency
5. Most important - Skillset of the development and testing team. If your development team is new to project and technology, then QA team will require more testing cycle for a stable build.

Without these factors you should not specify testing cycles number 'N'. Each development cycle will be followed by a testing cycle to ensure the quality of the product as a whole. Also, Extreme Programming (XP) is currently one of the most well known agile development life cycle model which uses TDD (Test Driven Development), which if followed correctly will reduce the number of unwanted testing cycles.

Comment: What about the number of testers on the project? Wouldn't that be an important factor?

Comment: Right, i.e. also important, I forget to add it, now I added the same to answer. Thanks for the same :)